# LDAP query in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run the below query in PowerShell with no success :(

```
((mailNickname=id*)(whenChanged>=20170701000000.0Z))(|(userAccountControl=514)(userAccountControl=66050))(|(memberof=CN=VPN,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl)(memberof=CN=VPN-2,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl))
```

Comment: what is this query? and what you are trying to achieve ? Which part is a Powershell cmdlet here? I can see only pipeline which is in PS and some dsqury object

Comment: Keep in mind that `userAccountControl` is a bitmap, not a simple numeric value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the contents of the query filter, I'd say you're looking for a user, so I'd suggest using the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet from the ActiveDirectory RSAT module:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '((mailNickname=id*)(whenChanged>=20170701000000.0Z))(|(userAccountControl=514)(userAccountControl=66050))(|(memberof=CN=VPN,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl)(memberof=CN=VPN-2,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl))'
```

Answer (score 21):

Without `Get-ADUser` cmdlet (ActiveDirectory RSAT module):

```
$Filter = "((mailNickname=id*)(whenChanged>=20170701000000.0Z))(|(userAccountControl=514)(userAccountControl=66050))(|(memberof=CN=VPN,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl)(memberof=CN=VPN-2,OU=VpnAccess,OU=Domain Global,OU=Groups,OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl))"
$RootOU = "OU=01,DC=em,DC=pl,DC=ad,DC=mnl"

$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($RootOU)")
$Searcher.Filter = $Filter
$Searcher.SearchScope = $Scope # Either: "Base", "OneLevel" or "Subtree"
$Searcher.FindAll()
```

Comment: I had to add a host name to the first argument of the DirectoryEntry constructor, and also a username and password as 2nd and 3rd arguments, for this to work. But this was the right, approach, thanks!