# How to get the Get-ADGroup users list from LDAP (PowerShell cmdlet) in windows

Tags: windows, powershell

How to get **AD-group users list from LDAP** using PowerShell without username and password.

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter (&(objectCategory=group)((cn=Testgrp"))))
```

I am trying this way but not fixing can anyone please help me out?

Right now I'm able to get the AD-Group info by using the below PowerShell scripts.

Get the group Info:

```
Get- ADGroupMember -Identify TEST_GRP_NM | select distinguishName | ft

Get-AdUser -filter{Name -like "GROUP_NM"} -Properties *
```

Get the user info:

```
Get-AdUser -Server "DOMAIN" -Identify "NTID" -Properties MemberOf
```

Note: Need to achieve the list of users from the LDAP group without using LDAP username and password

Comment: It's redundant to use `objectCategory=group` when searching for a *group* using `Get-ADGroup`.  You also have to extra closing parenthesis with a random single double-quote inside your `cn=.."`. The whole filter should be wrapped with quotes as well. `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(cn=Testgrp)'` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use this script to crawl through the AD (from another [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608470/14498055))
In case it becomes somehow a broken link:

```bash
# Your filter
$Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)((cn=Testgrp))))"

# The path you want to scan
$RootOU = "OU=AnotherOU,OU=AnOU,DC=etc,DC=Something"

# The scope Base, One-level or Subtree
# The name is explicit enough
$Scope = "subtree"

# Instanciation and configuration of the directory searcher
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($RootOU)")
$Searcher.Filter = $Filter
$Searcher.SearchScope = $Scope

# Getting results from the AD
# A first pipe to get the member property returning a list of member
# A second pipe to display each member of the list in a line
$Searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object {$($_.Properties["member"])} | Foreach-Object {"$($_)`n"}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks LeauHic. 
I'm getting below error. Do I need to install any dependencies in powerShell?                                                   Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "There is no such object on the server.
"
At line:20 char:1
+ $Searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object {$($_.Properties["member"])} | F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryServicesCOMException

Comment: There is no dependenies to install, this error mesage can come from a wrong AD path root. If you can have access to a distinguished name of a group (which will be something like "CN=GroupName, OU=..., OU=..., DC=...") you can compare the two paths